# How to unsubscribe particular entity from csubs using subscribe_id in fiware orion

Tags: fiware-orion, unsubscribe

i couldn't find particular **subscribe_id** to unsubscribe particular entity from **csubs**.

If i can use customize **subscribe_id** instead of **auto generate id**, it is easy to unsubscribe particular id.

But i couldn't set customize id, when call subscribe(self, entity_id, entity_type="openmtc", fiware_service="") in orion_api.py

Regards
Janaka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As decribed in [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/), you get the resource URI associated to the subscription at creation time (i.e. in the response of the `POST /v2/subscription` request) in the `Location` HTTP header. For instance:

```
Location: /v2/subscriptions/abcde98765
```

That URI is the one to use to retrieve (GET), modify (PATCH) or delete (DELETE) the subscription. In the later case the request would be as follows (without any payload):

```
DELETE /v2/subscriptions/abcde98765
```

In addition, you can get a list of subscriptions using `GET /v2/subscriptions`. Each subscription includes and `id` field, that can be used in the same fashion to get, modify and/or delete the subscription.